# PHP not displaying some UTF-8 characters correctly

Tags: php, mysql

PHP is retriving data from MySQL database. Now it's suppose to display the results to screen, but since my database contains characters like (ä,ö,ü,õ), which PHP displays (�,䄔). Database displays all characters correctly, so I don't think the problem is there.

I add following line to my code, that sets charset to UTF-8.

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

After adding that line, PHP displays following characters „”.

Also tried:

```
$conn->query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

How can I get PHP to display correct characters?

Here is the important part of my code

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT name FROM employee";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($employee);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "$employee|";
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

I'm running on PHP 7 and MySQL 10.1.19-MariaDB.

Comment: Follow these examples including error output - do you get an error? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Tried it before, didn't get any errors.

Comment: And have you done this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following things in this situations.

Make sure the header match the following

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

and try setting UTF-8 in html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

The source file encoding can make problems when string are hard coded in file. Since this file echoing it that seem to be no issue.

Comment: you can also call `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` at the very beginning or your code

Comment: I did try that solution at that time, but found out that problem was in java client side program. Anyway still good solution, maybe it'll help someone.